# Booting from USB to install Windows 7 on Macbook Pro, Early 2011

Tags: windows, bootcamp, install, usb, startup

I used Bootcamp (5.0) to create a Windows 7 install USB. It successfully created the install USB but when I reboot the system and hold down the option-key to boot from the USB drive, the boot-loader doesn't give me the option of booting from USB.

I also tried recreating the install USB from another Windows 7 machine using Microsoft's own Windows 7 USB creation tool but I still don't get the option of booting from USB on my mac.
What am I doing wrong here? Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you have to do it manually? From experience, I just had to create the disk, and Boot Camp automatically rebooted to the drive.

Comment: Have a look at http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/62700/49601

Answer (score 1):

You need to format the USB drive to use the GUID partition type -- use the Disk Utility on your Mac.

source [Apple support docs](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1948)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if your mac still has an optical drive, you are forced to boot Windows from a DVD (and won't be able to boot it up from the USB).

Comment: Do you have anything to support this?