# How to use OSX to create a bootable USB key to install Windows 8.1 on a PC

Tags: macos, usb, windows

I have a PC laptop without OS and I would like to install Windows 8.1 on it.

How can I prepare a bootable Windows USB key in Yosemite?

I have to use OSX to prepare the bootable USB Key, as I have no Windows machine to create it on.
Is it possible? How can I do it?

I saw this post: [Creating A Bootable USB Of Windows 8.1 On OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103874/creating-a-bootable-usb-of-windows-8-1-on-os-x)
but here the final destination seems another Mac.
Have I to follow the same procedure?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about running OS X on non-Apple hardware.

Comment: Not sure it is - I read it as using OS X to create a bootable Windows USB stick, to then use that to install Windows on a PC.

Comment: This question has been put on hold for the wrong reason.

Comment: I've edited for clarity of intent & voted to re-open

Comment: As from 10.10 I am not quite sure if it is still possible to make NTFS journal. However, once you got bootable it does not matter what the destination is: another mac or windows.

Comment: I really didn't get, why this question received a "-1" ...rules that I will never understand...
so, any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I'd follow the linked method & see where you get; after that, this question could be edited to clarify any additional difficulties you face.

Comment: i tried the linked method for create a bootable key. 
the boot loader in the pc doesn't recognise the key...

Comment: @ehijon UEFI or BIOS boot method? Or better add the laptop model to your question.

Comment: UEFI
Lenovo Ideapad S400U

Answer (score 1):

Quick shot:

1. Download and install [VirtualBox](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.20/VirtualBox-4.3.20-96996-OSX.dmg)
2. Create a new Windows VM with your Windows 8.1.iso (x64)
3. Copy the Windows 8.1.iso (x64) to your VM (network sharing)
4. Download and install [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/)
5. Plug in your thumb drive and attach it to the VM
6. Create a bootable thumb drive with Rufus. You may even choose UEFI or BIOS.

Not smart but it should work...

*I'm searching for a faster way without creating a VM*

Comment: @Klamath... hehe, i thought to do something like this, but it's looong process... i'll try it in case :)