# Blank screen after Bootcamp procedure

Tags: bootcamp, partition, windows

I'm trying to install Windows 7 using Bootcamp.

My computer is a iMac with Yosemite.

First challenge was create a USB Stick with Window Image, because my Bootcamp didn't give me this option. I solved with this post: [Bootcamp - No ISO Option](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170759/bootcamp-no-iso-option)

Everything worked fine, but after the restart I get a blank screen and after few seconds I get the message in a black screen: No bootable disk found (or something like that).

So, I need to restart holding Alt key, to select the OSX disk.

[image: Partition after run Bootcamp]

I'm stuck after this.

Comment: I don’t really understand the question. If you just want to install windows 7 with bootcamp, here is a tutorial you can follow: [Bootcamp Tutorial](https://youtu.be/lmR1gjhjiko). Also, this question was posted a long time ago, so just comment back if you already figured this out.

Comment: Hi @AnExistingPerson. Thanks for share the tutorial. Actually, I gave up to install it.