# OSX El Capitan - cannot make bootable usb stick with boot camp

Tags: macos, bootcamp, usb, startup, windows

I meticulously followed this tutorial, and this worked for me in 2014. I have a 4GB usb stick plugged into the computer. It should be enough for windows 7, a partition which no longer boots and I am hoping to run startup repair on it from the install USB so I don't have to start over clean.

tutorial: http://tsentas.net/create-a-windows-7-or-later-version-install-disk-missing-on-el-capitan/

This is the screen I get after following this tutorial where the Info.plist file of bootcamp is modified to let the USB creation happen (same screen as before):

[image: Select tasks download the latest windows support software from apple]

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170759/bootcamp-no-iso-option answers there did not help

Answer (score 13):

If you find no option to select your external USB drive as an ISO target - are instead directed to install on your repartitioned hard drive immediately - open the info.plist and add your model identifier to the following:

```
<key>ExternalInstallOnlyModels</key>
<array>
    <string>MacBook8,1</string>
    <string>MacBook9,1</string>
    <string>MacBookAir7,1</string>
    <string>MacBookPro11,5</string>
</array>
```

Comment: thanks you sooooo much for this answer!!!!! It's very unobvious parameter name for this case, but getting works for me (```MacBookAir7,2``` ```osx 10.12 sierra```)

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an older thread, but I had to combine several items as mentioned in other answers to get this to work on my iMac running OS Sierra (mac os 10.12.5).

Instead of disabling SIP, I copied the Boot Camp Assistant to my desktop, allowing me to edit the contents without disabling.  I still had to add the administrator as a read/write user by ctrl-clicking on the new Boot Camp icon, and selected show package contents.  Edit the permissions for the content folder and for the info.plist file.

Once I was able to get into the contents and edit the info.plist file using Xcode, I had to remove the 'pre' from the USBBootSupported Models key and add my model version there.  I also had to add the model version to the ExternalInstallOnlyModels key as Sohma pointed out.  Took  a bit of work, but I once I edited the correct keys, I was able to select the option in Boot Camp Assistant to create a Windows 8 Bootable USB.

Comment: Thanks for the great insight! Worked for me!
Friendly reminder to anyone trying to edit the plist, make sure you edit it with vim, nano, Xcode... etc. Anything that will not modify the formatting or encoding. (i.e. TextEdit will not work.)

Comment: That worked for me as well! If you need help with your model identifier just refer to the list in this Apple page: https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201634

Comment: This solution worked on El Capitan.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what you need to do. On El Capitan, you don't have permission to edit the info.plist file, and giving yourself that permission is not possible without disabling the rootless feature in terminal, which I would not recommend. Instead, simply copy Boot Camp Assistant to another folder, then you will be able to edit and use that copy. I copied it to my Downloads folder, edited the info.plist file to include my model identifier and it worked on the first try. No reboot, no nonsense.

If you're using a text editor, it may look something like this. Just look for the USBBootSupportedModels key (if it says PreUSB, change it to just USB), then add a string with your computer's model identifier.

[image: Exhibit A]

Edit: You may still have to give yourself permissions to the app after copying it, but the copy enables you to do just that. Simply click the app, and go to File > Get Info, then at the bottom of the window that pops up, give yourself permission.

Edit 2: There are several places that might block / allow your mac model from creating an image. I found that adding my model to <key>ExternalInstallOnlyModels</key> did the trick.

Comment: Tried this, did not help for whatever reason.

Comment: It has worked in the past with previous releases of OSX however

Comment: I just tried first answer tip and it worked.
I copied the Boot Camp Assistant app to a random folder, edited the info.plist and made a bootable USB out of a Windows 7 64bit iso. You should retry and be sure to edit correctly the file.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to disable SIP on the Mac and then it will allow you to edit the Info.Plist

Answer (score -1):

I m just a dentist whom happens to be a geek ..I was lucky but i just copied the boot camp to the desktop  edited the info.plist on xcode then just rased the preusb... opened the bootcamp again and voila i had the create a  win7 usb option ..
Does this make anysens to you guys ?

Comment: You copied and opened the Boot Camp *what*?  Not sure what you're getting at here.