# Windows install from DVD or USB on El Captain

Tags: bootcamp, usb, windows

I am learning about Mac more and more every day but I got stuck on this problem - trying to install Windows 7 or newer on El Captain.

I've been trying to put the .iso file on the USB but BootCamp would not recognise it. Now I have a clean DVD but I have no option in BootCamp to choose the installer disc as in this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170759/bootcamp-no-iso-option).

I tried to edit the info.plist file from the BootCamp package but when I wanted to put it back it would not let me. Turns out, the folder permissions are set only to read despite being the user with admin access. When I try to change the permission to write/read, I get this [error](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7261398).

I am starting to think I will never be able to run Windows on this Mac. It is mid-2010 27-inch with El Captain 10.11.1, any advice what the next step would be? I am deliberately trying to use the BootCamp and not VMware.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you trying to install the 32- or 64-Bit Version of Windows 7?

Comment: @J.C.Hi, the one I was trying to install is Windows 10 x64 downloaded from the Microsoft site, full file name Win10_English_x64.iso. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Reboot into Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> while the MacBook starts.
2. Navigate to Utilities and then Terminal.
3. Enter `csrutil disable ; reboot` which will disable System Integrity Protection (SIP) and restart the MacBook (Disabling SIP will allow us to replace the original Info.plist with the modified one).
4. Once booted back to normal mode, enter `mv Desktop/Info.plist /Applications/Utilities/Boot\ Camp\ Assistant.app/Contents/` in Terminal to replace the old Info.plist with the modified one.
5. Reboot the machine back into Recovery Mode again (using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).
6. Enable SIP using `csrutil enable ; reboot`.
7. All finished! Once Boot Camp Assistant launches again, the option “Create a Windows 7 or later version install disk” will appear.