# Modifying bootcamp (link include) - Error when writing Iso on USB stick

Tags: bootcamp, usb, disk-utility, windows

Thank you for your tutorial for modifying bootcamp for Early 2008 MacBook Pro...
[Bootcamp - No ISO Option](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170759/bootcamp-no-iso-option/220716#220716)

On my side, modifying Bootcamp to add the new option have worked perfectly, but i always got an error when Bootcamp write the Iso to USB...
I tried with 2 different USB sticks...
If someone have an idea, that would be great...

**Edit:**

So I tried [the VirtualBox method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/180263/93229), but I have a problem when I arrive to: step 12:

When I enter in terminal: `sudo  fdisk  -e  $DISK0  <<<"$INPUT"`
I get: Error the resource is busy...

May be it is because at step 7, I am not sure of the correct syntax :
they ask to modify `PARTID="$DISK0"s"$PARTITION"` 
I entered: `PARTID="$disk0s4"s"$PARTITION"`

Is it correct? Any ideas please?

**Edit 2**

With El Capitan, I have been able to write an iso on my 320 Go USB HDD (without power cable) or an 8 Go Sony USB stick.
But the problem is when Boot Camp Assistant restarts to install Windows, the "WININSTALL" disk is not discovered and I get a black screen with "insert an Windows disk and press any key".

I don't understand why at reboots my Windows installation disk/stick is not used by Boot Camp.

I can try with a Firewire HDD to see if it work better, but if I can use the USB I would prefer it. The only FW HDD I have is my backup HDD.

Comment: What is the model/year of your Mac? Not all Macs can install Windows using a USB stick.

Comment: It is an macbook pro mid 2010 (sorry i made an error when i was writing my question)...
Model : MacBookPro6,2
Bootrom : MBP61.0057.B11

Comment: You can not use a flash drive to install Windows on your model Mac. Is there a reason you did not use your optical drive?

Comment: Yes, since an Apple Update or OSX release, (i don't remember which one) i cannot burn DVD DL... it always give me an error. And any iso or .dmg cannot be burned on DVD DL...

Comment: What version of Windows are you trying to install? What version of OS X are you currently running? It is possible to install Windows without the use of a DVD or USB stick.

Comment: I am running OSX 10.10.5 (14F1509), and i am trying to install Windows 7/8 PRO...

Comment: @Cedric `PARTID="$disk0s4"s"$PARTITION"`is wrong, the resulting PARTID=s$PARTITION = probably "s4" (because $disk0s4=NULL)

Answer (score 1):

I will forward you to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179486/boot-camp-install-of-windows-7-issue-no-bootable-devices/180263#180263). To install Windows you will have to first install a free copy of VirtualBox. This software takes very little drive space and is required to boot from the Windows iso file. If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: OK thankyou, in fact i understand what you mean, i tried with Wine and Bottlewine, but i blocked at the "accessing the USB" problem...
With Wine and Winebottler i haven't succeffully allowed it to use the USB Stick, or DVD (i didn't tried DVD)...
ISO2USB cannot reach USB stickj, Rufus is the same...
In fact i can select an ISO but cannot select an destination Disk, the menu is blank...
May be with VirtualBox it would be better...
Thankyou :)