# How can I modify Boot Camp Assistant so it can use bootable USB?

Tags: bootcamp, imac, windows, usb

I own a 2011 21,5" iMac, and I need to install Windows to run some software that is Windows only.

I have done this in the past by altering Bootcamp assistent so it can use bootable USB drives, which is not natively supported on the 2011 iMac. (as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBAQ3CNgfxc/))

Now lately I reinstalled my iMac, so I wanted to modify Boot Camp again. As it turns out Apple 'fixed' this workaround by making bootcamps internal files not editable anymore.

So after I realized I couldn't use a USB drive, I tried using a bootable DVD, this didn't work, since Boot Camp gave me the message that "There is no bootable USB drive installed". 
In other words, Boot camp thinks it needs a bootable usb drive, when those aren't supported on my model.

So my question; does anyone know a way to work around this 'fix'?

Comment: What version of OS X is install on your iMac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot Camp Assistant.app - among other apps in the Utilities folder - is protected by System Integrity Protection as outlined [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209705/93229).

By disabling SIP you will be able to [edit the info.plist again](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/192687/93229).

So boot to Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> while booting.

- Open Terminal.app (menubar -> Utilites -> Terminal)
- Enter `csrutil disable`
- Reboot your Mac
- Edit the file */Applications/Utilities/Boot Camp Assistant.app/Contents/Info.plist*
- Reboot again to Recovery Mode and enable SIP again: `csrutil enable`
- Reboot your Mac

---

You should also be able to edit the file directly after booting to Recovery Mode without disabling SIP:

```
/Volumes/name_of_main_volume/usr/bin/nano /Volumes/name_of_main_volume/Applications/Utilities/Boot\ Camp\ Assistant.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

You'd have to make notes how and what to add though because you may have no real internet access.

---

Even if you can create a USB Windows installer, this does not necessarily mean that you can boot your Mac to Windows using this flash drive.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked, I had to make a few more minor adjustments to the file than before to make it work with a bootable USB drive, but you helped me a lot!

Comment: What were the other adjustments you had to make? I'm stuck on this for now.

Comment: @jtanman You have to prepend an (at) to send a message to Johan directly (example: `@Johan`)

Comment: Ah it was such a hassle even when I got the option to do it, it just kept giving me an unable to format my usb drive error. Ended up borrowing a Windows and used Rufus and did it in one try.

Answer (score 0):

I have a version of the Modified Boot Camp Assistant that I made. It should work with your Mac.

Download only if you have properly secured your mac. If someone replaces this with a malicious package, you could be at risk.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1emw_qeIGZqq5CTR30HPhNQJWs8s5y6_a/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How is this modified and how do we know that we can trust this executable?

Comment: I second the above comment from Mark -- red security flag for someone posting a modified executable via a quasi-anonymous link. OP may mean well but the internet is (and has been for years) too dangerous to recommend this kind of trust-by-default approach.