# Edit info.plist to make bootable USB

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, usb, windows, bootable-disk

Running OSX El Capitan 10.11.6 and trying to make a bootable USB for windows 7 bootcamp on my MacBook Pro. I disabled the SIP by using Terminal in Recovery Mode but I still cannot replace or edit the info.plist file. Optical drive is broken so that's not an option. Any advice appreciated!

Comment: You really should state what Info.plist file are you trying to edit and explicitly how you're trying to edit it.

Comment: I think he means enabling USB drive support in Boot Camp for Macs with optical drives. For example: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170759/bootcamp-no-iso-option

Comment: The info.plist is in the bootcamp contents and by deleting the "pre" in "preUSB" allows be to make a bootable USB. Otherwise I have to use the CD drive, but I can't because mine is broken and I have no plans to fix it due to cost and I never use it.

Answer (score 1):

It is pointless to solve your problem. If you succeed in creating the USB Windows installer, you probably will not be able to boot from the installer on your Mac. You are suppose to use the optical (DVD) drive.

There are alternative methods to install Windows 7 on your Mac. For example, see the question: [Boot camp install of Windows 7 issue, no bootable devices](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179486/boot-camp-install-of-windows-7-issue-no-bootable-devices).