# How to fix a dual boot (rEFInd) when Windows is not booting?

Tags: bootcamp, partition, windows, efi

I used **bootcamp** and **rEFInd** for dual boot of OS X 10.9.5 and Windows 7 on Macbook Pro 17" Early 2011. Worked well and stable.

I tried to setup a **third partition**, using the free space of the first one, and formatted it FAT **using the disk utility of OS X**. I did not touch anything from within Windows.

After this, rEFInd did not show up and

```
No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key
```

Deleted the newly created partition.

rEFInd shows up and lists two boot options. **I can boot into OSX - but upon chosing the second option rEFInd cannot find a bootable Windows partition any more.**

I am not able to add the free space to the OS X partition. There are 30 GB left and if I change the size of OS X from 50 to 80, it adjusts the value to 50 again.

[image: disk utility]

The [creator](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/index.html) of rEFInd was so kind to point me to gdisk as a tool to solve this problem.

My partitions look like this

```
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 234441614
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 56299597 sectors (26.8 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          409640        98749479   46.9 GiB    AF00  BVMACPRO
   3        98749480       100019015   619.9 MiB   AB00  Recovery HD
   4       156317696       234440703   37.3 GiB    0700  BOOTCAMP
```

MBR looks like this:

```
Number  Boot  Start Sector   End Sector   Status      Code
   1                     1       409639   primary     0xEE
   2                409640     98749479   primary     0xAF
   3              98749480    100019015   primary     0xAB
   4             156317696    234440703   primary     0x0C
```

gpt and diskutil output is:

```
$ sudo gpt -r show disk0
gpt show: disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640   98339840      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   98749480    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  100019016   56298680         
  156317696   78123008      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  234440704        911         
  234441615         32         Sec GPT table
  234441647          1         Sec GPT header

$ diskutil cs list
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```

Comment: A better answer: [Lost Windows Bootcamp boot entry after resizing the partition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256893/lost-windows-bootcamp-boot-entry-after-resizing-the-partition)

Comment: Just to keep you posted: I tried the answer David Anderson provided and the output now is "Missing operating system" and I am still not able to change the size of the partition via disk utility.