# How to fix an accidentally created Apple CoreStorage Volume, LVG, Logical Volume Group (broken partitions)

Tags: startup, partition

I used Unetbootin and accidentally chose a partition on my HDD to install the Lubuntu Live-USB I wanted to create on an USB Stick.

Now, my HDD looks like this

[image: iMac HD]

I can boot into Mac OS X and everything works fine.

This is a 4TB SHDD. Is there any option to recreate the original settings with only one partition?

GPT fdisk (**gdisk**) shows the following:

```
Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
partition table automatically reloaded!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): x

Expert command (? for help): o

Disk size is 7814037168 sectors (3.6 TiB)
MBR disk identifier: 0x00000000
MBR partitions:

Number  Boot  Start Sector   End Sector   Status      Code
   1                     1   4294967294   primary     0xEE

Expert command (? for help):
```

**gpt** and **diskutil** output is:

```
    BVs-iMac-3:~ bvimac$ sudo gpt -r show disk0
Password:
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  2728147912      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  2728557552     1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  2729827088        1264         
  2729828352  2529234944      4  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  5259063296      262144      5  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  5259325440  2554711695         
  7814037135          32         Sec GPT table
  7814037167           1         Sec GPT header
BVs-iMac-3:~ bvimac$ diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 28A99931-20D1-4D0C-8B5A-9872BC7270E2
    =========================================================
    Name:         LINUX
    Status:       Online
    Size:         1294968291328 B (1.3 TB)
    Free Space:   1294632738816 B (1.3 TB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 42D47656-F1D4-4FE4-BAB2-D572CA06D233
        ----------------------------------------------------
        Index:    0
        Disk:     disk0s4
        Status:   Online
        Size:     1294968291328 B (1.3 TB)
```

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo gpt -r show disk0` and `diskutil cs list`to your question.

Comment: BTW you didn't create a Linux LVM (UUID: E6D6D379-F507-44C2-A23C-238F2A3DF928) but a Apple CoreStorage LVG (UUID: 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC)

Comment: Is this the same system as http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271092/how-to-use-gdisk-to-fix-a-dual-boot-when-windows-is-not-booting ?

Comment: No. The other one is a Laptop with a currently unbootable Windows partition. This one here was an iMac where Unetbootin went the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

- Open Terminal and enter:

  ```
  diskutil list
  diskutil cs list
  ```
- Verify (and repair) the volume if necessary:

  ```
  diskutil verifyVolume disk0s2
  ```

  If a repair is required boot to Recovery Mode and repair the main OS X volume.
- Delete the Logical Volume Group

  ```
  diskutil cs delete 28A99931-20D1-4D0C-8B5A-9872BC7270E2
  ```

  This should convert the LVG LINUX to a normal partition
- Then enter `diskutil list` again and erase the 134 MB and the 1.3 TB partition (use the proper disk identifiers found in your listing above here):

  ```
  diskutil eraseVolume Free Space disk0s5
  diskutil eraseVolume Free Space disk0s4
  ```
- Verify the volume again:

  ```
  diskutil verifyVolume disk0s2
  ```
- Check the limits of disk0s2

  ```
  diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 limits
  ```

  This will output something like that:

  ```
  For device disk0s2 iMac HD:
      Current size:  1.4 TB (1396811730944 Bytes)
      Minimum size:  ? 
      Maximum size:  ?
  ```
- Try to expand the main volume - you can't expand the volume beyond the limit shown in the previous output

  ```
   diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 R
  ```

  If the `R` size option fails try to use a real size like `3999g` or a percentage `100%` (on some external disks this may fail because of some 2 TiB limit).

  ```
   diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 3999927271424b
  ```

  or

  ```
   diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 100%
  ```

Comment: @Ben I read your other question. [David Anderson](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/107222/david-anderson) probably provided an answer to your question already. I don't find the duplicate though.

Comment: The answer helped. I deleted the LVG. But i cannot resize the disk0s2.  Maximum size is I as current size. I suspect it is because the Recovery partition is in the way. I was able to do it via disk utility, though.

Comment: @Ben It's usually possible to resize a HFS partition and a subsequent Recovery partition. It's not possible to resize 3 partition at once (e.g. hfs+recovery+ntfs -> free space). A resize may also fail after modifying the partition layout with Boot Camp.

Comment: After using this answer my recovery partition was broken and I had to remove it. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271254/can-i-savely-remove-a-broken-recovery-partition

Comment: @Ben The commands in my answer shouldn't touch the Recovery HD!

Comment: @Ben Hmm, `diskutil resizeVolume ....` usually considers the integrity of the EFI, the RecHD and the two gpts. So resizing to 100% doesn't really resize to 100% but to size_of_disk-40 blocks(1stGPT 4096 aligned)-409600 blocks (EFI)-1269536 blocks(RecHD)-40 blocks(2ndGPT 4096 aligned)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52906/discussion-between-ben-and-klanomath).