# Can I safely remove a broken recovery partition?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, partition, diskutil

Can I remove the broken recovery partition?

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS iMac HD                 4.0 TB     disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot                         577.3 MB   disk0s3
```

And

```
$ diskutil verifyVolume disk0s3
Error starting file system verification for disk0s3: Unrecognized file system (-69846)
```

I am running Mavericks, original installation was Snow Leopard, on an iMac mid 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer my own question since it was straightforward.

Did this

```
$ diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ Blank /dev/disk0s3
```

Now disk utility says

```
Partitionstabelle für „ST4000DX001-1CE168 Media“ überprüfen
Voraussetzungen überprüfen
Die Partitionsliste überprüfen
Nach einer EFI-Systempartition suchen
Die Größe der EFI-Systempartition überprüfen
Das Dateisystem der EFI-Systempartition überprüfen
Alle Loader-Speicherplätze von HFS-Datenpartitionen überprüfen
Das Volume „iMac HD“ auf „disk0s2“ hat 0 Byte nachfolgenden Loader-Speicherplatz und benötigt 134217728 Byte.
Bei der Partitionstabelle sind Probleme aufgetreten, die den Startvorgang möglicherweise verhindern.
Fehler: Die Partitionstabelle muss repariert werden, da eine Datenpartition Speicherplatz für den Loader benötigt.
```

So I repaired the whole disk with disk utility which fixed the missing space for the loader.

I am now going to create a new recovery partition.