# Cannot boot windows 7 bootcamp after resizing partition

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

I decreased the partition size of my macbook and on windows used Partition Wizard to increase the partition of my windows however after the process was completed I was unable to launch windows( It failed to boot and have me an error 0xc000025). I can still see the windows disk on launch when pressing command and can also see it on the mac osx partition i.e my files are there it just isnt booting. Please help  !
MacBook Pro 13-inch mid 2009

```
Last login: Sun Dec  8 17:47:30 on ttys000
localhost:~ aku$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *160.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS MacBook HD 2            86.1 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                49.0 GB    disk0s4
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *15.5 GB    disk1
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 UNTITLED                15.5 GB    disk1s1
localhost:~ aku$ sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0
Password:
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  168153144      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  168562784    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  169832320        128         
  169832448   47046656      4  
  216879104   95700992      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  312580096       1679         
  312581775         32         Sec GPT table
  312581807          1         Sec GPT header
localhost:~ aku$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk0
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 19457/255/63 [312581808 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE    0   0   2 -   25 127  14 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
 2: AF   25 127  15 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  168153144] HFS+        
 3: AB 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 168562784 -    1269536] Darwin Boot 
*4: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 169832448 -  142747648] HPFS/QNX/AUX
localhost:~ aku$
```

Comment: Hello David , I am using mac osx 10.9.5 . I do not have a working optical drive. And yes i did use boot camp assistant to install windows 7.

Comment: No I believe it was installed via a usb drive

Comment: I have edited my answer with the partition tables can you check it

Comment: It is actually possible and in fact I have just installed windows 7 via a flash drive again now from scratch unfortunately i wasnt able to get my previously stored data. PS I used this link in my bootcamp assistant to allow me to use a usb drive https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170759/bootcamp-no-iso-option

Comment: Well, that is why I did not want to say you were wrong. I assume since you reinstalled Windows 7 that now everything is working OK? All the hardware/drivers are working and you can access the Windows volume from OS X?

Comment: Yes everything is alright now , thank you for the help david :)

Comment: It sure did not take long for them to shoot down your new question about install Windows 8.1.

Comment: Can not you use the Windows 8.1 USB installer to upgrade? I thought you could run the `setup.exe` program on the Windows 8.1 USB installer from Windows 7.