# Boot Camp partition is no longer accessible (El Capitan build 15A225f)

Tags: bootcamp, partition, macos

I have recently upgraded to the El Capitan Beta, which has caused a conflict with the Windows 8.1 Bootcamp installation on my MBP (see my previous question: [Is it possible to Bootcamp Windows 8.1 using USB on Late 2011 MBP?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191040/is-it-possible-to-bootcamp-windows-8-1-using-usb-on-late-2011-mbp)).

At startup, the option to boot from Windows is no longer available, and the partition has become invisible on Disk Utility.

I am running 10.11 build 15A225f

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
    #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
    0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
    1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
    2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            250.1 GB   disk0s2
    3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
    4:       Microsoft Basic Data                         30.6 GB    disk0s4
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
    #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
    0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +249.7 GB   disk1
                             Logical Volume on disk0s2
                             IDIDIDIDIDID
                             Unencrypted
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the build of El Capitan you run with this issue

Comment: Hi Mike. I've included the build.

Comment: I wish I had another upvote. What does `diskutil list` show you for the partition status. I'd love to help, but I'm in the dark how to proceed quite yet.

Comment: There are two disks: /dev/disk0 (internal, physical) and /dev/disk1 (internal, virtual) - the former has a Microsoft Basic Data partition with no name, a size of 30.6GB and identifier of disk0s4. This probably isn't useful, but I'm not sure what info to provide.

Comment: Sorry, I think I increased the size of the partition, so the second one:    0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +249.7 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 ID-HERE-NOT-SURE-IF-SAFE TO-SHARE                                 
Unencrypted

Comment: @Ryan Please add fundamental info like the `diskutil list` output to your question by editing and properly formatting it and not in the comments. You may scramble any UUIDs though.

Comment: + diskutil list output added to question

Comment: Still awaiting guidance on this. Have since updated to the public release.

Comment: @Ryan: [This guide](http://nerdr.com/bootcamp-partition-lost-repairing-mac-partitions/) should help you fix it.

Comment: @Ryan: Please also see [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/210730/68458) to find out how to turn off SIP protection in El Capitan. You'll need to turn it off to make changes to the Master Boot Record.