# Repairing 0xc000000e Windows error

Tags: bootcamp

I have a 2015 MacBook Pro running OS X 10.11 and I originally partitioned the SSD into two - then I used the Bootcamp Assistant to install Windows 8.1 on the second partition, everything was fine for a few months.

I then made the Mac OS partition smaller and created a third partition, I didn't resize the Windows partition.

Windows 8.1 then refuses to start, I get a blue-screen-of-death with the following message:

```
Recovery
Your PC needs to be repaired
An unexpected error has occurred.
Error code 0xc000000e
```

None of the F8 options (Safe Mode, etc) help.

I saw similar (though not identical) issues that people reported fixing using `gdisk` and `fdisk` - I went through those instructions and they didn't help.

I've made a new bootable USB stick to reinstall Windows with, the idea being once I could boot from it I could repair my installation, but the Boot Manager (Alt/Option during startup) won't let me boot from the USB stick.

I don't want to nuke the Windows partition because reinstalling all of my software takes a long time (over 4 hours).

Comment: Did you try removing the other partition and going back to your original configuration? It sounds like Windoze is looking for its partition to be a particularly designated partition and it is now confused.

Comment: You are really describing two problems. The first is not being able to boot windows from a USB stick. So how did you create this stick? Did you use the same iso as when you first installed Windows 8.1? Did you use the Boot Camp Assistant? Or did you create the USB using Terminal application commands? Was the Boot Camp Support Software also on this USB stick?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I thought Macs didn't boot from USB sticks by-design. I created the stick using a tool that makes bootable USB sticks from ISO images. I have an original Windows 8.1 setup disc imaged on to the stick (I made using the Rufus tool on Windows from another computer). When I use the Bootcamp Assistant it just tells me to delete/restore the disk, it won't let me create a new USB stick. There is no Bootcamp software on the USB stick right now.

Comment: Try this method: [Creating A Bootable USB Of Windows 8.1 On OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103874/creating-a-bootable-usb-of-windows-8-1-on-os-x). It has enough up votes, there must be something to the method.