# How to burn Windows 10 ISO to USB?

Tags: windows, usb, iso

I've been googling for hours; everything I can find either is for Bootcamp or doesn't work.

So, I have a clean PC that I want to install Win10 on; I also have a Mac with a Win10 ISO and a flash drive; how do I put the ISO onto the drive? I've tried using Unetbootin, but the PC doesn't boot from it.

My Boot Camp Assistant does not support burning ISO's to USB; it just installs from ISO directly.

Comment: Use MS's own Media Creation Tool from within Windows. https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10ISO but you can't get there on a Mac, you get redirected

Comment: @Tetsujin The problem is --- I don't have Windows!

Comment: You said you had Boot Camp, I extrapolated... wrongly, I guess

Comment: @Tetsujin Boot Camp Assistant, sorry. I've fixed it in the question

Comment: If you use Unetbootin to create a Windows 10 USB you need to use the UEFI boot option, NOT the Legacy Boot option when picking the USB drive to boot from.

Answer (score 2):

First, by "flash drive" we both understand external USB flash drive, right? :) If not, then get one :) Make sure it does **not** contain any important information.

1. Insert clean USB flash drive into your mac
2. Start standard Disk Utility
3. Select your USB flash drive on the left panel
4. Click 'Restore' button in Disk Utility window
5. In the dialog window click 'image' button and select your ISO image
6. From drop-down list in the same dialog window select your USB flash drive
7. Press 'Restore'

You should get properly prepared Windows 10 USB installation disk.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And all I get is "could not validate source --- invalid argument"...

Comment: Oops, sorry! I've missed one important point. Between 1 and 2 - simply double click your ISO image to get it mounted (you'll see disk appeared in your desktop). After that follow the steps. This shall fix 'invalid argument' warning :)

Comment: nope, the error is still there

Comment: Sad. Then try following this answer: http://superuser.com/a/226148

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same error as @Akiiino — and the method (`hdiutil -format UDRW` in the other answer hasn't given me a bootable USB-stick *either*. /=

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE, did you have a chance to try this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103874/creating-a-bootable-usb-of-windows-8-1-on-os-x ? It is mentioned in the very top...

Comment: This method didn't work for me, but Unetbootin did once I selected the UEFI USB drive option instead of the Legacy Boot USB Drive option.