# How to create a bootable Windows 10 USB with a Mac to boot/install on a PC?

Tags: high-sierra, windows, usb, bootable-disk

I have no access to a Windows machine at the moment, but need to create a bootable Windows 10 USB stick from a Mac that can be used to boot and install on a PC (not a Mac).

[Microsoft provides the ISO file](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO)

Can I just copy that ISO file to the USB and boot to it? I would use the Media Creation Tool, but you can't if you're on OS X.

For reference, my Mac is on High Sierra.

Comment: Do the answers on [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/103874/88313) not work for you?  There's already a bunch of questions about this topic with accepted answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating A Bootable USB Of Windows 8.1 On OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103874/creating-a-bootable-usb-of-windows-8-1-on-os-x)

Comment: I'm not trying to install it on my mac.

Comment: You could use free VirtualBox to install and run Windows in a virtual machine on your Mac from that iso file and then on this Windows virtual machine run Rufus application to create a bootable usb drive from that iso. Unlike many other solutions that you can find on the internet this solution works for sure with Windows 10 iso file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try "MS-DOS FAT" formatting with "Master Boot Record" scheme a flash drive. Next mount the download of the current version of Windows 10. Copy all the files from the mounted ISO to the flash drive. Try booting on a Windows machine.

If this does not work, then you could install VirtualBox. This is a free product. You can install Windows as a virtual machine, then use the Media Creation Tool to create the flash drive.